# specifically in SQLite on android, do views need to be "refreshed" if you change the schema of the table they are built off of?

Tags: android, sqlite

Simple question really. We have to do this on sql server, but sqlite on android is a totally different paradigm.  For example you can't drop columns.  I was wondering if anyone knew if a view (with a select * in it) needed to be dropped and readded if you changed the schema of the table.  There is as far as i can tell no refresh view command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

This has nothing to do with Android specifically but is a generic SQLite question and is about "Database Views" not the common Android "Views"

The SQLite documentation might help https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html
and https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html as the answer depends on what you are doing to the schema.

Table and Column Rename and Column Add all work automatically when not using column names and SELECT *

**Update:**

Database views in SQLite just store the SQL used to generate the view in the `"main".sqlite` table

So a view created with `CREATE VIEW test AS SELECT * FROM myTable`
 shows up in the `sqlite_master` table as `CREATE VIEW test AS SELECT * FROM myTable`

There if you add a column to `myTable` then the SQL for the view if you did re-create it would be exactly the same

The docs say DROP and re CREATE if doing other stuff

**Update:**

If doing other stuff to tables you will probably need to "Create New Table", "Copy data in to new Table", "Delete old table", "rename New table to Old table name"

As as you can `DROP` a table without dropping a `VIEW` referencing it then you could probably not need to update the view in this case as well

If you want to play with this without writing code you can start an emulator then use `adb shell sqlite3` from a command line in the platform tools to run the sqlite3 command line tool on the device.

And as SQLite itself only has `CREATE` and `DROP` Database Views, Android won't have any more that that.

Comment: i don't think you completely understood my question.  I was asking for example I add a column to a table, do i need to do anything to a view in sqlite that is built off of it? MSSQL has a rebuild command for views but sqlite doesn't seem to.

Comment: Yes I misread the question, it really is not an Android Question and it would have been better if the question had said "Database views" not just "views" very close to word "Android" as I took it as "Android views" as "View" is a very common concept in Android. Updated based on my experience of "SQLite Database Views"

Comment: can you explain a little better?  I read over that document and i can not determine if adding a column would require me to drop and add a view.  It "seems" to say no because the schema is text but it's not outright displayed.

Comment: Explained how sqlite stores views and why you don't need to change them when using `SELECT *`. As the documentation is sparse on some of the details I've added how you can quickly see what it is doing using the command line sqlite3 tool